# Regex with capture groups

Tags: php, regex

I' trying to match some patterns with a regex and also being able to capture sub-patterns  (full pattern must be valid, sub pattern should be extracted.

Some of my patterns are:

> **20170408143311101**_rdds.22;the-context=+39-20170408143311101@127.0.0.1-***SET_PARAMETER***.*xml*
>
> **20170408143311101**_rdds.22;the-context=+39-20170408143311101@127.0.0.1.*xml*
>
> **20170408143311101**_rdds.22;the-context=+39-20170408143311101@127.0.0.1-***SET_PARAMETER***
>
> **20170408143311101**_rdds.22;the-context=+39-20170408143311101@127.0.0.1
>
> **20190502085933954**_tel.111;the-tag=+39-20190502085933212@127.12.13.14-***TEARDOWN***.*xml*
>
> **20190502085933954**_tel.111;the-tag=+39-20190502085933212@127.12.13.14-***TEARDOWN***
>
> **20190502085933954**_tel.111;the-tag=+39-20190502085933212@127.12.13.14
>
> **20190502085933954**_tel.111;the-tag=+39-20190502085933212@127.12.13.14.*xml*
>
> **20190502085928958**_tel.0222;the-context=myco.local-20190502085928958@127.0.0.1-***SET_VARIABLE***.*xml*
>
> **20190502085928958**_tel.0222;the-context=myco.local-20190502085928958@127.0.0.1-***SET_VARIABLE***
>
> **20190502085928958**_tel.0222;the-context=myco.local-20190502085928958@127.0.0.1
>
> **20190502085928958**_tel.0222;the-context=myco.local-20190502085928958@127.0.0.1.*xml*

The subpattern are highlighted as:
**date**: bold
type: plain
***attribute***: bold italic
*ext*: italic

NOTE:
the "_", "-" and "." characters used as sub-separators should not be taken into the capture groups.

EX:
sub-pattern of

```
20170408143311101_rdds.22;the-context=+39-20170408143311101@127.0.0.1-SET_PARAMETER.xml
```

are:

```
date = 20170408143311101
type = rdds.22;the-context=+39-20170408143311101@127.0.0.1
attribute = SET_PARAMETER
ext = xml
```

Now I tried with

```
^(?<date>\d{17})_(?<type>.*)-?(?<attribute>\w*)?\.?(?<ext>\w{3})?$
^(?<date>\d{17})_(?<type>.*)(-(?<attribute>\w*))?(\.(?<ext>\w{3}))?$
```

but collpses type attribute and extension inside the "type" capture group

when

```
^(?<date>\d{17})_(?<type>.*)-(?<attribute>\w*)\.(?<ext>\w{3})$
```

does not take into account options

How could I improve the expression to take each pattern (if present) in its capture group

I'm really stuck!

Answer (score 2):

Try that. I have not checked all the data.

```
^(?<date>\d{17})_(?<type>.+?)(?:-(?<attribute>\w*))?(?:\.(?<ext>\w{3}))?$
```